# Не работает замена символов

Tags: java, android

Не работает замена символов в массиве. Вот код замены:

```
        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "Начало замены символов");
        for (int j=0; j<dictionaries.length; j++) Log.i(TAG, MSG + dictionaries[j]);
        for (int j=0; j<dictionaries.length; j++) dictionaries[j].replace('_', ' ');
        for (int j=0; j<dictionaries.length; j++) Log.i(TAG, MSG + dictionaries[j]);
        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "Замена символов завершена");
```

Вот вывод в лог:

```
09-17 01:06:48.941: INFO/APP(31014): ....SelectDictionary: Начало замены символов
09-17 01:06:48.941: INFO/APP(31014): ....SelectDictionary: Word_1
09-17 01:06:48.941: INFO/APP(31014): ....SelectDictionary: Word_2
09-17 01:06:48.941: INFO/APP(31014): ....SelectDictionary: Word_3
09-17 01:06:48.941: INFO/APP(31014): ....SelectDictionary: Word_1
09-17 01:06:48.941: INFO/APP(31014): ....SelectDictionary: Word_2
09-17 01:06:48.941: INFO/APP(31014): ....SelectDictionary: Word_3
09-17 01:06:48.941: INFO/APP(31014): ....SelectDictionary: Замена символов завершена
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы исполняете выражение, но не присваиваете его результат ячейке в массиве. Делайте так:

```
for (int j=0; j<dictionaries.length; j++)
{
    dictionaries[j] = dictionaries[j].replace('_', ' ');
}
```